# iPhone - NSTimer - Peculiar task needed

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I know how to set a timer and when timer expires, it fires and a action is caught.
What I'm expecting is that after 30 seconds of every one hour of real time that that `"xx:00:30"` I have to check my server for updates.
I know how to communicate with server. But how can I create such a timer that fires every `"xx:00:30"`.

I don't want to run the timer if the app is in background.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you checked NSTimer's `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` or `setFireDate:`? With real time you mean the current date/time? If yes, that method should serve you. Within the selector just schedule the next timer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Marcus in his last message,

```
NSTimer's initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: or setFireDate:
```

works.